# Writing an element from an integer array using write()

Tags: c

Suppose I have the following `int` array

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

For my program I want to use `write()` to write `a[1]` to a file descriptor.

This what I was told to do by a friend

```
n = a[1];
buf = write(fd, &n, sizeof(n));
```

I'm confused since the second parameter should a pointer to a character array. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: If you're referring to the [POSIX `write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html) system call, the second parameter is not `char*` its `const void*`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) the second argument to `write` is of type `const void *`. So basically anything<sup>*</sup> goes, as long as what it points to is at least as long as the third argument indicates.

<sup>* That is: any data-pointer. Function-pointers are not compatible with `void *`</sup>